# Retrieve latest rows based on the condition and its previous rows action column on a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Dataset:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp(
user_id [int]  NOT NULL,
date [datetime] NOT NULL,
fieldid [int] NOT NULL,
fieldvalue NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
fromvalue [int] NULL,
tovalue [int]  NULL,
action char(1) NOT NULL,
audit_date [datetime] NOT  NULL
)

Insert into #temp values ( 1,'2020-01-01',1,'a',NULL,0,'C','2020-01-01 21:00:39.000 ');

Insert into #temp values ( 2,'2020-01-01',1,'a',NULL,0,'C','2020-01-01 21:00:39.000 ');
Insert into #temp values ( 2,'2020-01-01',1,'a',NULL,0,'N','2020-01-01 22:00:39.000 ');

Insert into #temp values ( 2,'2020-01-01',1,'b',NULL,0,'C','2020-01-01 21:00:39.000 ');
Insert into #temp values ( 2,'2020-05-05',1,'a',NULL,0,'C','2020-05-05 21:00:39.000 ');
Insert into #temp values ( 2,'2020-05-05',2,'a',NULL,0,'C','2020-05-05 21:00:39.000 ');
Insert into #temp values ( 2,'2020-05-05',1,'b',NULL,0,'C','2020-05-05 21:00:39.000 ');
Insert into #temp values ( 2,'2020-05-05',3,'c',NULL,0,'C','2020-05-05 21:00:39.000 ');

Insert into #temp values ( 3,'2020-01-02',1,'a',NULL,0,'C','2020-01-01 10:00:39.000 ');
Insert into #temp values ( 3,'2020-01-02',1,'a',NULL,0,'N','2020-01-01 11:00:39.000 ');
Insert into #temp values ( 3,'2020-01-02',1,'a',NULL,0,'C','2020-01-01 12:00:39.000 ');

Insert into #temp values ( 4,'2020-10-10',1,'a',NULL,0,'C','2020-01-01 22:00:39.000 ');
Insert into #temp values ( 4,'2020-10-10',1,'a',1   ,0,'U','2020-01-01 23:00:39.000 ');`
```

condition
 include only the latest row when fromvalue = 0 and tovalue = 1 with action <> 'N' for a given userid, date, fieldid,fieldvalue given date

sql query

```
with cte as
(
    select user_id, date, fieldid, fieldvalue, fromvalue, tovalue
        , action, audit_date
        ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, date, fieldid, fieldvalue ORDER BY audit_date desc) AS 'rnk'
    from #temp (nolock)  
)
select * from cte where rnk = 1 and action <>'N'  and fromvalue IS NULL and  tovalue = 0 ;
```

i think got this query now .so far working .please review .

Note:Edited the original post based on valid comment. i am new to this and i will post DTD hereafter.My apology

Comment: First - stop splattering [nolock everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is NOT a best practice. Next, encourage others to help you by posting a script with DDL and sample data. Otherwise you push the work of writing that to your readers. Why does that help you? For one, you have no column in [table] (nice name btw) named data_to_value or data_from_value. Writing a script will find those typos. Notice also the inconsistent usage of underscores in your names.

Comment: And instead of pre-fixing `with` with a semi-colon `;`, get in the correct habit of terminating all statements with a semi-colon.

Comment: edited the original question based on comment. Thanks @SMor for sharing the link. i am new to this and my apology for not posting it clearly. seems like the query is working

Comment: @SMor i read the article and it suggested to use SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; can you share your thoughts on when exactly with nolock can be used and when not to use . Thanks in advance

Comment: @Rocky3151 That linked article also has links to others and you can find many articles on the use of NOLOCK by searching the internet. Generally speaking, you don't use that hint without knowing and accepting the consequences. Incorrect data and Errors are just some of the problems. And generally speaking, it is rare IME to need that hint. I've never had to use that hint

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt using `row_number()` is quite there, however need to move the whole filtering logic to the subquery, where the window function is computed. Otherwise, rows that do not match the criteria might be ranked first, and then be excluded in the outer query.

This should do what you want - note that your description of the filtering specification does not match the query (I used the predicates of the query, which better match your sample data):

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by user_id, date, fieldid, fieldvalue
            order by audit_date desc
        ) rn
    from #temp t
    where fromvalue is null and tovalue = 0 and action <> 'N'
) t
where rn = 1
```

For your sample data, **[this produces](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dff829452fb9897e4c8ccd49391dd830)**:

```
user_id | date                    | fieldid | fieldvalue | fromvalue | tovalue | action | audit_date              | rn
------: | :---------------------- | ------: | :--------- | --------: | ------: | :----- | :---------------------- | :-
      1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |       1 | a          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-01-01 21:00:39.000 | 1 
      2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |       1 | a          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-01-01 21:00:39.000 | 1 
      2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |       1 | b          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-01-01 21:00:39.000 | 1 
      2 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00.000 |       1 | a          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-05-05 21:00:39.000 | 1 
      2 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00.000 |       1 | b          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-05-05 21:00:39.000 | 1 
      2 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00.000 |       2 | a          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-05-05 21:00:39.000 | 1 
      2 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00.000 |       3 | c          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-05-05 21:00:39.000 | 1 
      3 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00.000 |       1 | a          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-01-01 12:00:39.000 | 1 
      4 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00.000 |       1 | a          |      null |       0 | C      | 2020-01-01 22:00:39.000 | 1
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB. my apology if the description is not accurate. rows that do not match the criteria might be ranked first, and then be excluded in the outer query. you are correct and i want to include only the latest record on the condition . the query i shared is working fine considering the condition . Thanks for your response